# Error: package com.google.android.gms.plus does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-plus

I don't understand why I can't import the package after couple hours of trying and searching.

I tried to change the gradle settings, delete .idea and .iml and re-import the project without it.

Comment: Refer sample at https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, add this in dependency

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'